# Selenium : Login With Unique Alphanumberic

Tags: java, selenium

May I know, how to read the verifyCode image and insert verifyCode into the text field on Login Page?

Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: As I know it is not possible, since the security image provider not giving you to alternative text. Instead you can use webservices for login and try to set browser's cookie for getting it logged in.

Comment: Actually verify code image [captcha] is to prevent automation and spamming and selenium is for automation , so you can not do this using selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got you right, you are looking for a solution to bypass capcha.

There are several libraries and frameworks written for it. Take a look [at DeathByCapcha](http://scraping.pro/solve-captcha-c-using-deathbycaptcha-service/) this is a pretty simple tool, and will work only with simple images. Hope it will help you